# Jquery: stuttering animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all i´m sorry for my poor english.

I have a problem with my code and can´t figure it out. I have a big background image in the div.beer. The div.beer is 150x150 big. The background-image is divided with a grid and every block in the grid is 150x150. It moves the background-image everytime the .animate runs -150px on the x-axis. It works all fine but its stuttering and i don´t know why?
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="persons">
    <div class="beer">
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var endPosition = [1067, 1062, 1073, 1078, 1084, 1056];
    var bgPosition = $('div.beer').css('background-position');
    var bgSplit = bgPosition.split('px');
    var bgX = parseInt(bgSplit[0]);
    var bgY = parseInt(bgSplit[1]);
    var i = 1;
    var beer = $('div.beer');
    $('div.beer').click(function(){
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
            anim();
            function anim(){
            beer.animate({
                'background-position-x': bgX-=150
            },50, function(){
                if(bgX <= -1650 && bgY <= -1650){
                    bgY = 0;
                    bgX = 0;
                };
                if( bgX <= -1650) {
                    bgX = 0;
                    bgY -=150;
                };
                bgPosition = beer.css({'background-position': bgX+'px '+bgY+'px'});
                i += 1;
                if(i<endPosition[x]){
                    anim();
                } else {
                    bgX = 0;
                    bgY = 0;
                    i = 1;
                };
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Could it be that the image is too big? Try using a smaller image.

Comment: The image is 2200x2200. I think that should work but i´m not sure. EDIT: Sorry, it´s 1800x1800. Had the wrong number in my mind.

Comment: Is your doctype declared? In Internet Explorer stuttering occurs if you don't declare your doctype.

Answer (score 0):

you need to camel case your properties in jquery to:

```
$(selector).animate({ 
                   backgroundPositionX: amountToAnimate 
                }, duration,...);
```

make sure the amountToAnimate is constant like -150

background-position-x/y is not part of any CSS spec, its IE specific CSS, added to IE5.5, and later implemented by Webkit.

Opera and Firefox do not conform to this standard.

you can use step to achieve this

http://jsfiddle.net/q9aeh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with your problem, but when you declare beer = $("div.beer"), you should use it:

```
//Saved! so use it!
var beer = $('div.beer');
var endPosition = [1067, 1062, 1073, 1078, 1084, 1056];
var bgPosition = beer.css('background-position'); //here
var bgSplit = bgPosition.split('px');
var bgX = parseInt(bgSplit[0]);
var bgY = parseInt(bgSplit[1]);
var i = 1;

beer.click(function(){ //and here
```

no need to select it again like:
$('div.beer').css('background-position');

Comment: Facepalming myself. Thanks sir. :)